# How can I pass a KeyError 2 in a set in Python?

Tags: python, set

I want to remove the Key Error 2 that states that the element does not exist in the Set. I have tried with set(None), I have tried with excep KeyError:pass...none of these work. Any idea?

```
def p6():
    myPossiblePrimes= set()
    myDividersList= set()


    for x in range(2,15):
        for y in range(2,10):
            if (x%y != 0):

                myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
                myDividersList.add(y)
            else :
                myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
                print (x, 'does equally divide with', y, ' and I removed it from the list')

    return[print('These are my possible primes:',list(enumerate(myPossiblePrimes)), 'and these are my dividers', list(enumerate(myDividersList)))]
```

Here is some of the return, which is why I added the else for removing it from the Possible
Primes:

8 does equally divide with 2  and I did not do anything
checked
9 does not equally divide with 2 and I added  9 into the possible set
9 does equally divide with 3  and I did not do anything
checked
10 does equally divide with 2  and I did not do anything
checked

Error:

File "C:\Python33\assignment 2.1.py", line 165, in p6
    myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
KeyError: 2

Comment: Where's your error? Can you give a traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the key before removing:

```
 if (x%y != 0): 
       myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
       myDividersList.add(y)
 elif x in myPossiblePrimes:
       myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
```

But there is a problem with the logic you have you are too greedy to add numbers into the prime list. Try something like this:

```
 for x in range(2,15):
    for y in range(2,10):
        if x%y == 0 and x != y:
            myDividersList.add(y)
            break
    else: # the part below is executed if for loop ended without a break
        myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
```

Comment: It's not working...It says it;s removing it but it's actually not      if (x%y != 0):
                myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
                myDividersList.add(y)
            elif (x in myPossiblePrimes):
                myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
                print (x, 'does equally divide with', y, ' and I removed it from the list')
            else: break

Comment: I'm a noob...let me think about it for a bit :D

Comment: It doesn't work for me though, as the list has to be ordered...so that I can extract a certain prime number :D

Answer (score 0):

To reduce your code to the problem:

```
if (x%y != 0):
    myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
else :
    myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
```

How can you remove it if you haven't yet added it?

Comment: Just want to add like None or something, so that it passes through. I understand what you are saying and you are right. The thing is that it must be removed, otherwise it will stay there and it won't be right. Thank you

Comment: You can check it's there first: `if x in myPossiblePrimes:`

Comment: @AndraV What do you mean when you say `it must be removed, otherwise it will stay there`? You're not adding `x` to `myPossiblePrimes`, so how will it "stay there" if its never put there to begin with?

Comment: because it will be put from the beginning, when the count will go higher...I exemplified from the Python Shell what's happening